# Capture Screenshot Of a Url (the website based on AngularJs) using c#

Tags: c#, angularjs, .net-4.0, screenshot, capture

I'm trying to capture a page without any success.

the page based on HTML(using angularjs) using ajax call to webapi.

if someone has any solution for me it will be nice(tried to used webBrowser.Navigate - but I'm getting the site before data binding - used thread.sleep in order to wait without any success) - 
p.s I'm getting sometimes Navigation Canceled page

my solution is .net 4

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with 3rd party library, I suggest you this nuget package [Freezer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Freezer/). It's free, supports HTML5/CSS3 and fits into a single dll.

```
var screenshotJob = ScreenshotJobBuilder.Create("https://github.com")
              .SetBrowserSize(1366, 768)
              .SetCaptureZone(CaptureZone.FullPage) // Set what should be captured
              .SetTrigger(new WindowLoadTrigger()); // Set when the picture is taken

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("output.png", screenshotJob.Freeze());
```

Comment: I can't use this dll (mvc is needed and my project based on web form )

Comment: Well, it should'nt mattter as long as you don't use methods that implies MVC.

Comment: on runtime the code throws exception that mvc dll is needed

Comment: @YonatanYasharzadeh : Can you show me a sample code ?

Comment: i double checked my code (its .net 4 and not 4.5 - and that why i can't use freezer - "Freezer needs .NET 4.5+ ." - and my colleague try to import the dll from another solution )  - i need dll that support .net 4 .